# Cannot install software on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, 16.04

I am a new Ubuntu user. its version is 16.04. I cannot install any software from Ubuntu software. A red signal is shown in the upper right corner.

[image: desktop]

Comment: Press ctrl + alt + T. type `sudo apt-get install -f`. Press enter. Type your password. Does that fix it?

Comment: when you click on the red icon it should show a dropdown menu with some extra information add this to your question.

Comment: As a follow-up to Tom's comment: If that command doesn't fix the issue, what was the output of the command? (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814))

Comment: Please update your post with the result of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and some information about how you installed Ubuntu 16.04 (fresh installation or upgrade + virtual machine?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your messed up packages.  Start with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If that's a no-go, try

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and then run the commands above.